# Get context at caret

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a IntelliJ IDEA plugin to get context at current caret. More specific, I need to get a list of variables' types and names that can be used at caret. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    // caret 1
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // caret 2
        row.createCell(i).setCellValue("X");
    }
    // caret 3
}
```

I need to get `wb: Workbook` at caret 1, `wb: Workbook, sheet: Sheet, row: Row, i: int` at caret 2 and `wb: Workbook, sheet: Sheet, row: Row` at caret 3 because `i: int` is no longer in the scope.

[This link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206755815-Getting-the-PsiElement-at-the-caret) seems related, it suggests `file.findElementAt(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset())`. This expression returns a `PsiElement` object. However, when I get context of this object and traverse the context using `PsiRecursiveElementVisitor`, it will visit elements defined after caret, which doesn't meet my requirement above.

My code:

```
public class ContextView extends AnAction {

    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
        final Editor editor = event.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
        final Project project = event.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.PROJECT);
        //Access document, caret, and selection
        final Document document = editor.getDocument();
        PsiJavaFile javaFile = (PsiJavaFile) PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(project).getPsiFile(document);

        PsiElement currentEle = javaFile.findElementAt(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset());
        PsiElement cxt = currentEle.getContext();

        cxt.accept(new PsiRecursiveElementVisitor() {
            @Override
            public void visitElement(PsiElement element) {
                System.out.println(element.toString());
                super.visitElement(element);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So how to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you need only local variables, or also fields of the current class and its superclasses and other declarations defined outside of the current method?

Comment: @yole For current need, local variables only is OK. But I think IDEA must maintain a list of all available variables for task like code completion. Is there any API I didn't notice?

Comment: "But I think IDEA must maintain a list of all available variables for task like code completion." 你说的是 `PsiReference` 的 `getVariants` 吧,这个是借助Stub和`processDeclarations`实现的,非常复杂,不过你可以试试调用`PsiElement#getReference`的`getVariants`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This link seems related, it suggests file.findElementAt(editor.getCaretModel().getOffset()). This expression returns a PsiElement object. However, when I get context of this object and traverse the context using PsiRecursiveElementVisitor, it will visit elements defined after caret, which doesn't meet my requirement above.

Have you tried `com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil#getParentOfType(com.intellij.psi.PsiElement, java.lang.Class<T>)`? You may fill the first argument with the result of `findElementAt`, and the second argument with `PsiDeclarationStatement.class`, which is the Psi class for variable declarations.

By this you can get the local variable declaration. You can test by `sout(parent.getText())`

Comment: This is an indirect way but it works good for getting all local variables. (BTW:  PsiReference.getVariants() no help.